# Cloudfoundry , Spring , MySQL Unknown initial character set index '192' received from server

Tags: mysql, spring, cloud-foundry

when i tried to run my page on cloudfoundry that uses MySQL i received this error

```
    org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: 
Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: 
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unknown initial character set index '192' received from server. 
Initial client character set can be forced via the 'characterEncoding' property.)
```

What did i miss ?
I did try below to change from my UTF-8 to LATIN, still receive the error

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY col1 VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET latin1;
```

Thanks for all the replies

i see

```
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
```

from cloudfoundry database

Answer (score 3):

i was using **mysql-connector-java-3.1.7-bin.jar**, and after change to **mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar** and it worked well.
tq

Answer (score 2):

check in your configuration in /etc/mysql the lines below. Comment them and try again. You have to restart the mysql service (/bin/vcap restart).

collation_server = utf8_unicode_ci

character_set_server = utf8

Comment: Hi nikos, how do I change it in hosted

Comment: Just open the file with a text editor (e.g. vi) and put a hash in each line.